# Why use buttons & forms for submitting a piece of data, when just icon image with onclick handling function may work as well?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, button

Why use `button`s within form for submitting a piece of data (such as for favorite-ing an question here on SO), when simply icon image with on-click JS handler function may work as well ?

Here the buttons I am referring to are like '**Vote-up**' buttons, or '**Favorite a question**' buttons on `stack overflow`. & not the **Submit an answer** button for which I would defintiely use forms and buttons.

I would like to simply put the icon images in place of my 'vote up' or 'favrorite' buttons and attach a click event handling function which would update my server via ajax. The reason being  this reduces & cleans-up my markup

---

**EDIT :**

I guess most of the biggest sites today like fb/ twitter etc are relying on JS & as I have just noticed they dont provide a alternate way for some of the most basic features like `liking a post` when javascript is disabled. I obviously dont need to go beyond those users. Thus by limiting myself  to JS enabled users I think I would be quite OK.

Comment: "Thus by limiting myself to JS enabled users…" That depends on your expected audience.

Comment: If "onclick handling" works just as well, then try unplugging your mouse and accessing those functions without it. (Not everybody is able to use a mouse).

Answer (score 3):

The vote-up & favorite button are anchor tags on stackoverflow (or I don't see what you're talking about!).

Also, I think it is better to use forms so that it degrades gracefully without JS.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an ajax post request for that, definitely. I think you're right. Use $.ajax or the shortcut $.post on the click event for the image. A loading effect is also important in terms of UX.

Answer (score 0):

> Why use buttons within form for submitting a piece of data (such as for favorite-ing an question here on SO), when simply icon image with on-click JS handler function may work as well ?

It might work. It might not work. HTML is solid and reliable. [Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/) and don't fall foul of [the Gawker problem](http://blog.adrianroselli.com/2011/02/beyond-hash-bangs-reliance-on.html)